# How i can upgrade ios flutter app on apple store?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

how to solve this problem please

This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [2.0.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [2.0]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring

Comment: As the message says, the version number needs to be higher. 2.0.1 would be acceptable as would 2.1. 2.0.0 is the same as 2.0

Comment: thx the problem is solved and uploaded my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to project settings and upgrade the version of your choice then you will be able to update app it is happening coz you are using app with same version no. to update.

Comment: @loqman please upvote my answer if it solved your problem